# textarea content created by ajax not inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have a piece of code written in php

i use ajax to display a textarea when a certain button is clicked. it works fine and it's being displayed.

next to the textarea there is a submit button created also by the same button-click, which should insert the textarea content into a database table once it's set. but that doesn't seem to work

any help? thanks

there is the ajax code:

```
function answer(post)
{
var xmlhttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","answer.php?p="+post,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this is answer.php:

```
<?php
$p=$_GET['p'];

if (isset($_POST['_submit']) && $_POST['_text']!="") {
    $answer=$_POST['_text'];
    include 'db_connect.php';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answer (p, answer) VALUES ('$p', '$answer')");
    mysql_close($con);
}
else {
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<textarea name="_text"></textarea>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="_submit" value="post"/><';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: your confusing us for stackpsychics.com where they can see your code through meditation...

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work". Does the browser make an HTTP request? Is the structure of the HTTP request what you expect? Does the server side script read the data correctly? Does it fail only when you try to insert the data (that you've confirmed as been received correctly) into the database? Does anything give an error message (either in the browser, in the HTTP response or in the server logs)?

Comment: can you paste your code that handles the ajax request that should save the contents to the database?

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug code that you don't provide. You should post the code that isn't working here so we can look at it.

Comment: hahaha stackphysics! ok so i posted the code. @david no error messages and yes it seems to make an HTTP request, as it displays everything it should.

Comment: does the query fails or the request? where you trigger the answer function?

Comment: Aigheee! Bobby Tables strikes again — http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: bobby tables? is that sql-injection? how did i manage to do that?

Comment: as far as my knowledge in mysql takes me, i say it's the query that fails. but there's a strong possibility that i'm wrong!

Comment: the answer function is triggered through onclick="answer(post)" in a button's properties

Comment: and where does the javascript `post` variable come from? It would help if you showed all the code instead of just a section.

Comment: that variable is ok i assure you it's working. i think it's a mysql issue

Comment: @David Dorward is that a mysql error? ican't figure out what's wrong

Comment: @gianniskpf — you take data out of `$_POST` and put it directly into a query without any kind of protection, so someone could submit things that trigger subqueries, delete table rows, and so on.

Comment: @David Dorward i just simplified the code i posted, so only the essentials remain in order to detect the problem.

Comment: Simplifying the code introduces additional problems. One explanation for it breaking is that the data includes a `'` character. If that isn't actually the code, and the data is properly handled, then that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the action attribute to the form?

Comment: Did you try to var_dump($_POST) to make sure your script is receiving something?